# JavaScript Mocha Selenium typing phrases in google

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js

I have a task to read phrases from file (I'm doing it in "beforeEach", they are saved to *phrases* Array) and read google headings by Selenium - save them to *output* array and then save *output* array to csv file in "afterEach".

```
it('Automation', async function() {
        await driver.get("https://www.google.pl/");
        await driver.manage().window().setRect({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
        for (let i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(phrases[i]);
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
            await driver.sleep(1500);
            await driver.findElements(By.css(".bkWMgd .rc h3")).then(async function(elements){
                if(elements.length > 0){
                    for(let j = 0; j< elements.length; j++){
                        let text = await elements[j].getText();
                        if (text!=""){
                            output.push({
                                phrase: phrases[i],
                                heading: text
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    await console.log(phrases[i]+" - no results");
                }
            });
            await driver.sleep(2000);
            await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).clear();
        }
    })
```

Output is like this (phrases bolded, headings not, it's around 10 headings per phrase):

**zte tv box firmware**    Updates and Firmware » Android TV Box update » WTFFIX ...

**zte tv box firmware**    ZTE ZXV10 B860HV2 is a New Android TV Box from ZTE ...

**zte tv box firmware**    ZTE Android TV box - ZXV10 B860H - RedFlagDeals.com Forums

**zte tv box firmware**    Backup Amlogic Firmware - FreakTab

(...)

**firmware tv box zte b860h**     Firmware stb zte b860h full root

**firmware tv box zte b860h**     Firmware stb tv box zte b760h

**firmware tv box zte b860h**     Pulpstone hg680

**firmware tv box zte b860h**     S905X-BV B860H : bootloader + boot + recovery - FreakTab

(...)

**zte axon desktop mode**      Can someone try usb-c to HDMI adapter with Z… | ZTE Axon 10 Pro ...

**zte axon desktop mode**      How to Start Remote Control Computer / Screen Mirroring in ...

**zte axon desktop mode**      ZTE Axon M (Z999) - Transfer Media To & From a Computer ...

**zte axon desktop mode**      ZTE AXON User Manual

(...)

Usually it works fine, but sometimes I have strange output. It looks like it stopped at some phrase and it keeps returning the same headings for different phrases to the end... What's wrong?

Comment: did U tried replace sleeps with wait.until ???

Comment: With await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.css(".bkWMgd .rc h3"))); it's even quicker and gets captcha. But I wonder - why it's gettting the same output as in previous phrase, I would rather expect no output?

Comment: .sendKeys(Key.ENTER) might not always work. Use submit or input click or pure js instead.